# Fetch data of two tables with/without match of Primary key and foreign key

Tags: php, sql

I am using this query.

```
select * from  customers E JOIN `customer_p` D ON (E.ID = D.`P_ID`)
```

Here E.ID is primary key of customers table and p_ID is foreign key of customer_p
This query fetches only those result in which primary key (ID) of customers table is present as foreign key (P__ID) of customer_p table and skips rest rows/data from customers table.

I want to fetch all date of customers table whether or not primary key (ID) do match with foreign key (P__ID). How can I do this?

Comment: That is why there is a `Left Join`

Comment: I dont know, if I understand correctly, but try LEFT JOIN -> `select * from  customers E LEFT JOIN customer_p D ON (E.ID = D.P_ID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN to get all rows in customers.
see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 1):

Please run below query:

```
SELECT E.*, D.* 
FROM customers as E 
LEFT JOIN `customer_p` as D ON D.P_ID = E.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select date from customers where not
(
select date from  customers E JOIN `customer_p` D ON (E.ID = D.`P_ID`)
)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your query such that others can learn from it